# Improving distance calculation

Tags: r, performance, loops, distance

I have build my own distance (let's call it `d1`). Now, I have a matrix for which I need to compute the distance. Considering `x` as the matrix with the content for each sample, the code written to get the distance matrix is the following:

```
# Build the matrix
  wDM <- matrix(0, nrow=nrow(x), ncol=nrow(x))

# Fill the matrix
  for (i in 1:(nrow(wDM)-1)){
    for (j in (i+1):nrow(wDM)){

    wDM[i,j] <- wDM[j,i] <- d1(x[i,], x[j,])

  }
}
```

I have to implement this process several times. So, **I was wondering if there is a faster way to fill the distance matrix `wDM` rather than using two for loops**.

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dist()` from `proxy package`. It lets you specify user-defined distance function by setting the parameter `method = #yourDistance` default would be `euclidean`. Check the documentation here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/proxy/proxy.pdf

Comment: Thank you. Only one issue; although I defined `d1` as a function of two vectors in the explanation of the problem, it also depends on a third constant variable (`d1(a,x1,x2)`), how can I pass this parameter into `"method"`?

Comment: I think setting a column as a constant vector `a` to your matrix should solve this.

Comment: Let's suposse that `a` is a vector of weights for 10 variables and I want to compute a weighted distance. I don't understand what you say..

Comment: Then define this `a` within your `distance function` and modify your `distance equation` accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I think `dist{proxy}` was what I was looking for. I'm going to open a new question to explain the problem of the additional parameters.