# Call distance function with three parameters

Tags: r, parameters, distance

I have defined a distance depending on two vectors (individuals) named `x1` and `x2` and a third vector of weights (`w`).

```
w.dist <- function(w, x1, x2){
# Define y1 and y2
  y1 <- x1/w
  y2 <- x2/w
# Define the distance directly
  w.d <- sqrt(sum(w*(log(y1/w.geoM(w,x1)) - log(y2/w.geoM(w,x2)))^2))
# Return the value
  return(w.d)
}
```

Related to a previous question I asked ([Improving distance calculation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45231861/improving-distance-calculation)) I want to use `dist{proxy}` function.

The problem is that **I don`t know how to specify my own distance with this additional parameter**. I have tried:

```
  # Define the vector of weights 
    w <- c(2,rep(1,9))
  # Try to compute the distances
    DIST <- dist(x, method = w.dist)
```

... but It doesn't work.
The unique solution is to make `w.dist` dependent only on `x1` and `x2`.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

As, I have mentioned before, rather than passing `w` as an argument, define it within your function `w.dist`.

Comment: That is the las trial I mentioned, but when I parallelize the code, I have problems with the `w` recognition.